# Fitch derivations for equivalence relation properties

Tags: logic, fitch

Primarily, this a request to check Fitch-style derivations in the file,

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1du-EIZG3CSdrcfDbldlzwgRftDzeVc8K/view?usp=drivesdk

This is not trivial. The reflexiveness derivation contains over 300 steps.

It is fine if no one steps up. I ask only because it is often difficult to see one's own errors in such detailed work.

As for "the philosophy" involved, the stackexchange community has little love for my views. For me, at least, this is a simple fact. Others may not recognize my writing style.

I will only retain a membership for a short time.

Nevertheless, the topic is one which has been of interest to category theorists (or, perhaps, to homotopy type theorists more specifically). In 2019 Quanta published the article,

https://www.quantamagazine.org/with-category-theory-mathematics-escapes-from-equality-20191010/

making great claims concerning the nature of mathematics relative to equality statements. The article illustrates the basic idea behind the work using a pretty graphic. The graphic is based upon a straightforward theorem from algebraic topology about the contractibility of sets in real spaces where every two points can be joined by a straight line segment.

By analogy, the "terms" of an equivalence relation correspond to the endpoints of line segments. The line segments essentially encode how the terms of its endpoints are substitutable for one another.

Essentially, this is a "topological gluing." Recognized as such, it becomes ubiquitous across mathematics. Differential manifolds, for example, are often described as "gluing" small patches of real spaces together with coordinate charts.

The technical details of such gluings always involve transitivity in termwise descriptions.

By contrast, my work lies effectively within the symbolic domain. Hence, the Fitch-style derivations.

I am an autodidact without many resources. Verification --- or any constructive suggestions --- would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: There is an error on page 45, in that line 314 is incorrectly indicated as line 313. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should learn a proof verification software , this is exactly what they were designed for. coq in particular is used heavily by ppl in HTT.

Comment: Having someone review your work (never mind the 77 pages) is unfortunately not really appropriate for a Q&A. There's probably some less structured discussion forum somewhere, where this would fit (although you're still asking a lot, and I'd probably suggest asking about one part at a time, if nothing else, or trying to get a formal peer review somehow). Also, pure symbolic logic may also be more in the maths domain, rather than philosophy.

Comment: @Joseph_Kopp Thank you. I found it. Even typos like this are helpful.

Comment: @emesupap Do you have a proof of program correctness for any proof assistant software and the compilers/interpreters that generate their machine-readable code? If you wish to ridicule that question, know that I had the privilege of studying topology with Wolfgang Haken many years ago.

Comment: @emesupap More likely than not, proof assistants implement classical logic with strategies which depend upon distributivity. In 1999, Pavicic and Megill showed that there is a non-distributive model of classical propositional logic. Their result had been algebraic in nature. In 2006, Schechter developed a syntactic method for non-distributive, classical propositional logic. I have no reason to "learn" a proof assistant just because that is for what they were "designed." I am concerned about the correctness of what I study.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Your reprimand is noted. Your suggestions of "somewhere" and "somehow" are largely unrealistic, although you probably do not realize that. I will check the post one more time tomorrow. Then, as promised, I will relinquish a logon and avoid the site. Give me two days; then ask the mods to remove the offensive post.

Comment: @mls programs are proofs, but ofc these are only at the object level. And in fact most modern proof assistants are not classical although one can axiomatize LEM if one wishes. In any case asking others for help checking fitch derivations is not in particular different from asking a machine, there is necessarily some trust involved either way

Comment: @mls All sites have rules. The rules here are more strict that most (even if not always enforced as diligently or consistently). I can't offer a more specific suggestion because I'm not that familiar with forums. [academia.se] is probably a decent place to ask *how* to get a peer review as an autodidact (but asking them for a peer review would **NOT** be appropriate). Case and point, I found this in a minute of Googling: [How to get feedback on unfinished research papers if I don't have any direct contact with people qualified in my field?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/156474/77932)

Comment: It's also not clear what you actually want to do with this document (e.g. publish it in some journal, put it in your book or try to prove something else entirely). Expanding on this could make it more compelling for someone to review. (Here's another related question: [How to get recognition of research as an independent autodidact?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/97219/how-to-get-recognition-of-research-as-an-independent-autodidact))

Comment: @NotThatGuy Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first formula you use in 1.1 is somewhat complicated, so let's simplify it. The formula is:

∀x∀y(xRy <-> [ ∀z ¬(¬x=z <-> (x=z ∧ zRy)) ∧ ∀z ¬(¬y=z <-> (y=z ∧ xRz))])

As part of this, you write ¬x=z <-> x=z ∧ zRy. Let's draw a truth table for that.

```
x=z   zRy   |  ¬x=z <-> x=z ∧ zRy
T     T        F
T     F        T
F     T        F
F     F        F
```

So this is equivalent to x=z ∧ ¬zRy. So let's replace that, and the other similar part of the expression:

∀x∀y(xRy <-> [ ∀z ¬(x=z ∧ ¬zRy) ∧ ∀z ¬(y=z ∧ ¬xRz)])

DeMorgan:

∀x∀y(xRy <-> [ ∀z (¬x=z ∨ zRy) ∧ ∀z (¬y=z ∨ xRz)])

Introduce implications:

∀x∀y(xRy <-> [ ∀z (x=z -> zRy) ∧ ∀z (y=z -> xRz)])

This is clearer, and now by inspection I can see this is a tautology. Because xRy, we already know that x=z -> zRy, and same for y=z, and the reverse is clear as well.

So what's the purpose of complicating the formula like that? I don't understand what you hope to gain.

Comment: Thank you causitive. Since you took the time to look at it, I will accept the answer and add to your reputation. In several places, David Hilbert states that formal axiomatics *presupposes* decidable equality. The use of the exclusive disjunction makes this explicit. The form of the formula is intended to condition relations to decidable equality as the language signature is expanded. When the signature is expanded with further relations, the new relation is associated with a second formula intended to formally constrain its interpretation. You can see this with any Step 3 and Step 5 at end.

Comment: @causitive: For the equality relation, the formula (Step 1 in the systems at the end) relates equality to the usage of the universal quantifier. Other systems I work on relate equality to the usage of the existential quantifier. This syntax is precisely the transitivity axiom (C6) from Tarski's cylindric algebra (see the second listing of axioms at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindric_algebra ) This embeds the existential quantifier into equality statements. In turn, this admits a capacity for implementing the management of existential import as in free logic.

Comment: Naturally, the inference rules must be different. Constants and functions are introduced with descriptive syntax, although not Russell's. And the "discernibility relation" from Step 5 on page 62 of the given file must also be used to accommodate the possibility of "non-existents." The inference rules are such that no term for a non-existent shall ever enter a proof. But, the axioms must accomodate the possibility. The methodolgy is directly comparable to what one finds in recursive function theory. But, this is work that no one will ever see. (Kafka's "Letter for the king")

Comment: Setting all of the previous comments aside, consider various notions of reductionism for a moment. It may be out of vogue, but, in principle, if someone proposes axioms from which extant "essential" axioms are derived, they "ought" to be intrinsically interesting. I have accepted that this is not the case. I have asked for assistance simply to know whether or not I have made a fatal mistake that I am missing.

Comment: @mls Hilbert states that formal axiomatics presupposes decidable equality? But equality is not decidable in the sense of "able to be decided by a Turing machine." There are many relations of equality that a Turing machine cannot decide. And yet this is not a fatal flaw in foundations of mathematics. Hilbert *asked* whether theorem-proving was decidable, but the answer given by Godel and Turing was "no."

Comment: I probably ought to have spoken of "effective equality." The specific statements I had in mind occur at the bottom of page 2 and the top of page 3 in the translation at https://docslib.org/doc/3504270/foundations-of-mathematics-vol-1-1934-david-hilbert-paul-bernays  He speaks of "previous delimitation" and "idealizing assumption" with respect to formal axiomatics. Hilbertian formalism is more than the proof theory of his metamathematics. The passage also speaks of "abstraction from the existential form" and a "wide axiomatics" different from the "narrow axiomatics" he focuses  upon.

Comment: I probably ought to have spoken of "effective equality." At the bottom of page 2 and the top of page 3 of the translation,  https://docslib.org/doc/3504270/foundations-of-mathematics-vol-1-1934-david-hilbert-paul-bernays  Hilbert speaks of "previous delimitation" and "idealizing assumption" in relation to a classical domain of discourse. The passage also speaks of axiomatization in terms of a "wide scope" and a "narrow scope." The question to which you refer involves his metamathematics with the identity criteria of "objects" to be the sensible impressions of symbols on a page of paper.